# React native check unchek not working for custom icons

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am learning react native,I am trying to use the check box. The plain check box which we import from react native. i.e import {checkbox} from react-native worked for me. But when I tried to use checkbox from react-native-elements it is not working. It only sets the default value for unchecked icon and it doesn't change.

```
<View style = {styles.containerForCheckBoxValues}>
  <CheckBox
    style={styles.checkBox}
    checkedIcon={<Image source={require('/root/VS_Code/JavascriptProjects/assets/Images/Checkboxactive/Checkboxactive.png')} />}
    uncheckedIcon={<Image source={require('/root/VS_Code/JavascriptProjects/assets/Images/Checkboxdefault/Checkboxdefault.png')} />}
    value={this.state.checkedForKids}
    onChange={() => this.onChangeCheckForKids()} />
  <Text style={styles.textViewStyleKidsStatusLabel}>Have Kids</Text>
</View>;
```

Answer (score 2):

On react-native-elements you have a prop `checked` it has to change between `true` or `false` that is what defines if it's checked or not. To change you can call a function `onPress`.

```
    <CheckBox
  style={styles.checkBox}
  checkedIcon={<Image source={require('/root/VS_Code/JavascriptProjects/assets/Images/Checkboxactive/Checkboxactive.png')} />}
  uncheckedIcon={<Image source={require('/root/VS_Code/JavascriptProjects/assets/Images/Checkboxdefault/Checkboxdefault.png')} />}
  checked={this.state.checkedForKids}
  title='Your title'
  onPress={() => this.onChangeCheckForKids()}
```

With multiple checkboxes the way I did was with an array. If you know how many checkboxes you are going to have it's easy, To every checkbox just "attribute" a number e.g. checkbox 1 is going to be position 0 in the array.
If you don't know how many you have I would set an extra key to your object.
would look like this:

```
let x = [{
        title: 'this is your title',
        id: 1,
        checked:true,
    }{
        title: 'this is your second title',
        id: 2,
        checked:false,
    }];
```

Full simple working example:

```
<CheckBox
title={'click here'}
checked={this.state.delivery}
onPress={() => this.setState({ delivery: !this.state.delivery })}/>
```

Comment: So how to do that an you give some example, I mean where do I check and unchek it and what if I have three checkboxes how to maintain state ?

Comment: Thanks but initially i would like to know how to use it in the tag <CheckBox because when i used their prop "checked" it did not work.

Comment: Does this example work for you?
`<CheckBox
  title='Click Here'
  checked={this.state.checked}
/>`

Comment: What is it supposed to do ??? check uncheck ?,first of all it shows some silly icon till i provide my own, it only shows the view getting clicked

Comment: See edit. It's a simple working example, from there your can customize it. for more details please visit their Docs https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/checkbox.html